# VS2013 with ReSharper 8.2 not recognizing Code Contracts?

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-2013, resharper, code-contracts

I have the following software:

- Visual Studio 2013 Update 2
- Code Contracts (1.6.60617.15)
- ReSharper C# edition (8.2.0.2160)
- ReSharper Code Contracts (1.0.0.0)

When I open a method with code contracts, ReSharper is confused about the contract:

[image]

It is warning me that `chapter` can be null, even though the contract requires it not to be. Also:

[image]

The contract invariant method is flagged as `never used`. Technically correct, but it should not tell me that because the method is used by the code contract rewriter to get information about each invariant. How do I go about teaching ReSharper about code contracts to correct these two issues?

Comment: Paste your code as a text, not as an image.

Comment: Also feedback to Microsoft. So, Microsoft will correct that issue in next update.

Comment: To demonstrate the issue, I needed the appearance of the issue as someone familiar with ReSharper environment would see it. What good would pasting the code do, @SonerGönül?

Comment: This is not a Code Contracts issue. It is a ReSharper issue, yet this scenario has been claimed to be supported. If anything, it should be reported to JetBrains, if this is indeed a bug @Shell. I'm here with a question to figure that out.

Comment: Just to make sure: Is Code Contracts Runtime Checking enabled in the project's properties and have you added CONTRACTS_FULL to the compilation symbols (Build section of the project properties)?

Comment: Yes, Code Contracts Runtime Checking is enabled, but I did not have the compilation symbol set to CONTRACTS_FULL. Adding it, however, does not seem to make a difference @Keith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this working for Portable Class Library, please do the following:

1. Create a new folder `ExternalAnnotations` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\Bin\` directory;
2. Put `System.Diagnostics.Contracts.xml` there with the following content:

   ```
   <assembly name="System.Diagnostics.Contracts">
   <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assume(System.Boolean)">
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
           <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
       </attribute>
   </member>
   <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assume(System.Boolean,System.String)">
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
           <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
       </attribute>
   </member>
   <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assert(System.Boolean)">
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
           <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
       </attribute>
   </member>
   <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assert(System.Boolean,System.String)">
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
           <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
       </attribute>
   </member>
   <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires(System.Boolean)">
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
           <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
       </attribute>
   </member>
   <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires(System.Boolean,System.String)">
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
           <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
       </attribute>
   </member>
   <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires``1(System.Boolean)">
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
           <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
       </attribute>
   </member>
   <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires``1(System.Boolean,System.String)">
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
           <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
       </attribute>
   </member>
   <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Invariant(System.Boolean)">
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
           <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
       </attribute>
   </member>
   <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Invariant(System.Boolean,System.String)">
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
           <argument>condition:false=&gt;halt</argument>
       </attribute>
   </member>
   <member name="M:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.ReportFailure(System.Diagnostics.Contracts.ContractFailureKind,System.String,System.String,System.Exception)">
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.AssertionMethodAttribute.#ctor"/>
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.ContractAnnotationAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
           <argument>=&gt;halt</argument>
       </attribute>
   </member>
   <member name="T:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.ContractInvariantMethodAttribute">
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.MeansImplicitUseAttribute.#ctor" />
   </member>
   <member name="T:System.Diagnostics.Contracts.ContractClassForAttribute">
       <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.MeansImplicitUseAttribute.#ctor" />
   </member>
   </assembly>
   ```
3. Close all Visual Studio instances (just to give ReSharper a chance to reload annotations), reopen Visual Studio and load needed solution;
4. There is a chance you will need to clean ReSharper caches (ReSharper | Options | Environment | General | Clear Caches);

Also I filed [a new ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-419146) about supporting such case in ReSharper ExternalAnnotations extension by default.

Answer (score 2):

I have since contracted JetBrains via e-mail support, and came to a sudden realization. I was working in a Portable Class Library solution.  I will attach the e-mail correspondence from my side to this answer and will update this answer with follow-up responses (If any) for those who might have a similar problem at this moment.

> Thank you for your quick reply. I have now installed 8.2.1000.4556 and
>   updated the ExternalAnnotations extension to 8.2.1001. The
>   aforementioned "ReSharper Code Contracts 1.0.0" plugin is actually
>   called "ReSharper.ContractExtensions 0.7.51" on the plugin page. I am
>   using .NET 4.5, and I did not define compilation symbols nor did I
>   reference any Code Contracts related library.
>
> However, I seem to have neglected to mention that I was working in a
>   Portable Class Library project. Since I did not think about this
>   possibility at all, I created a test project to test my ReSharper
>   installation with. I used a regular project and a Portable Class
>   Library project. The result may not be surprising for you: everything
>   works as intended in the regular project, but Code Contracts are not
>   recognized in the Portable Class Library.
>
> It is therefore easy to conclude that there is no support yet for
>   Portable Class Libraries, or this is merely something that has not
>   been tested. I have attached the test project to this e-mail. If you
>   open the "Class1.cs" file in the "ClassLibrary1" project from VS2013
>   Update 2 with ReSharper 8.2.1, you should see the same warnings as I
>   do.
>
> I hope you will consider adding support for these project types. I can
>   only imagine it is something little going wrong in a support
>   detection, but alas, I do not know your code base nor should I try to
>   guess. I can only hope you will consider this feature.

Comment: Use Alexander's answer. He's the one from JetBrains support that has been helping me.